# Transform Single Row to Single Column with Reference Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Problem:
I often need to refer a row to a column (using =Cell).  When I need to do it with multiple row, I just use Ctrl+Shift+Enter. But it is annoying because error: "you cannot change part of an array" when I would like to edit something.

Explain expected result:
I would like to choose the range which is the single row without a header.

```
Dim cRangeColumn As Range
Set cRangeColumn = Application.InputBox("Please choose a range", "Specify Range", Type:=8)
```

After I press "OK", it should let me choose where I put my row(single row which is transposed of the column) - a cell address to let the program knows where to start

Again, this can be done by

```
Dim rRangeRow As Range
Set rRangeRow = Application.InputBox("Please choose a range", "Specify Range", Type:=8)
```

Problem I face:
How to access the value in range

The logic:

1. I get the range of the columns - let say `$E$29:$E$37` - Total 9 value
2. I choose the start address of the transposed column (a row), let say `Sheet226!$G$14`
3. Program start to write `="$E$29  to the starting address "Sheet226!$G$14"`, then write 
   until `$E$37` is meet.  Each time it writes, offset 1 column.

Comment: I got the answer for this one.  Because it has not been posted for 8 hour so I cannot post the solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After swimming in the ocean, I was able to make this work

[image]

I try to use the "< code > " but it does not look well. So I take the snapshot of the code. It is not lengthy.  I wish it does not bother.