# How to create a reference between a column and a row of another sheet and vice versa - Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have asked and provided my own answer, although it is not good but it works. 
[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467639/transform-single-row-to-single-column-with-reference-excel-vba)

However, now I would like to link cells from another sheet. However, the program I wrote could not make reference among cells from one sheet to another sheet.

**Example**

Sheet1, Column A

Sheet2, row 1

I want to have

```
Sheet1!A1 = Sheet2!A1
Sheet1!A2 = Sheet2!B2
```

[image]

Comment: `I would like to link cells from another sheet, it cannot refer to cells at another sheet` I am unable to understand what you mean by this...

Comment: @SiddharthRout I changed my wording.  I mean right now if I want to link cells with my program (from row to column and column to row), it works. However, if I want to link cells between two sheets, it does not work.

Comment: `Sheet1!A2 = Sheet2!B2` Did you mean B2? If yes then `Sheet1!A3 = Sheet2!C3`? Or did you actually meant `Sheet1!A2 = Sheet2!A2` so `Sheet1!A3 = Sheet2!A3`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have posted a picture. Bascially, I need to link (="cell") among cells of a column to a row, and a row to a column. My current program only works if cells are on the same sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying by any chance?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim cRange As Range, rrange As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim cPrompt As String, cTitle As String
    Dim rPrompt As String, rTitle As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    cPrompt = "Please Choose a Column without Header"
    cTitle = "Specify Column Range"

    rPrompt = "Please Choose Starting cell"
    rTitle = "Specify row Range"

    Set cRange = Application.InputBox(cPrompt, cTitle, Type:=8)
    Set rrange = Application.InputBox(rPrompt, rTitle, Type:=8)

    For i = 1 To cRange.Count
        rrange.Offset(j).Formula = "=" & cRange.Parent.Name & _
        "!" & cRange.Cells(1, i).Address

        j = j + 1
    Next i

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me a lot recently.  Basically I would like to link a row to a column but they are on different sheets.    Your code works but it links randomly.  Program will: 1. Require to select a range (which is a row) as source 2.  Require to select a cell address (on another sheet) as destination. 3. Program starts to fill the cells on a column with "=" cells' address (from another sheet - source of step 1).  Right now, I could do a link between cells of column and row or row and column on same sheet.  Then do the link but I have to link 2 times.

Comment: That is what the above code does. I just tested it. Let's say you are in Sheet2. Run the above code. Select `A1:D1` in Sheet1 when the first inputbox shows. Then select `A1` in Sheet2 when the Second inputbox shows. You will notice that the formulas get updated in Cells `A1:A4` in Sheet2. Isn't this what you are trying?

Comment: Yes, it works - I did something that caused the problem.  Thank you very much. @Siddharth Rout

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a much simpler way by using the INDIRECT function, something like so:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!R1C"&ROW()+4,FALSE)
```

This uses the current row plus an offset value to line up the current row with the first column that you want to reference. As you copy the formula down the row number will increase but will be used to increase the column reference.